# Distributing values of specific rows proportionally among other rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I’m trying to distribute the values of two specific rows (“unknown” and “to_investigate”) proportionally among other rows in a BigQuery table. The distribution should be based on the existing values of the other rows. After the distribution, the rows with “unknown” and “to_investigate” should disappear from the result.

Here’s the query I’m currently using:

```
    WITH
  daily_totals AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    SUM(IF(channel_name NOT IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), first_touch_value, 0)) AS total_first_touch_value,
    SUM(IF(channel_name NOT IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), last_touch_value, 0)) AS total_last_touch_value,
    SUM(IF(channel_name NOT IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), linear_touch_value, 0)) AS total_linear_touch_value,
    SUM(IF(channel_name NOT IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), markov_value, 0)) AS total_markov_value
  FROM
    `aardy-348311.MTA_result_marketer.MTA_data_purchases_no_repeat_marketer`
  GROUP BY
    date ),
  unknown_values AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    SUM(IF(channel_name IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), first_touch_value, 0)) AS unknown_first_touch_value,
    SUM(IF(channel_name IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), last_touch_value, 0)) AS unknown_last_touch_value,
    SUM(IF(channel_name IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), linear_touch_value, 0)) AS unknown_linear_touch_value,
    SUM(IF(channel_name IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate'), markov_value, 0)) AS unknown_markov_value
  FROM
    `aardy-348311.MTA_result_marketer.MTA_data_purchases_no_repeat_marketer`
  GROUP BY
    date )
SELECT
  m.date,
  m.channel_name,
  m.first_touch_conversions + (u.unknown_first_touch_value * m.first_touch_conversions / NULLIF(d.total_first_touch_value, 0)) AS first_touch_conversions,
  m.first_touch_value + (u.unknown_first_touch_value * m.first_touch_value / NULLIF(d.total_first_touch_value, 0)) AS first_touch_value,
  m.last_touch_conversions + (u.unknown_last_touch_value * m.last_touch_conversions / NULLIF(d.total_last_touch_value, 0)) AS last_touch_conversions,
  m.last_touch_value + (u.unknown_last_touch_value * m.last_touch_value / NULLIF(d.total_last_touch_value, 0)) AS last_touch_value,
  m.linear_touch_conversions + (u.unknown_linear_touch_value * m.linear_touch_conversions / NULLIF(d.total_linear_touch_conversions, 0)) AS linear_touch_conversions,
  m.linear_touch_value + (u.unknown_linear_touch_value * m.linear_touch_conversions / NULLIF(d.total_linear_touch_conversions, 0)) AS linear_touch_conversions,
FROM
  `aardy-348311.MTA_result_marketer.MTA_data_purchases_no_repeat_marketer` m
JOIN
  daily_totals d
ON
  m.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN
  unknown_values u
ON
  m.date = u.date
WHERE
  channel_name NOT IN ('unknown', 'to_investigate')
```

When I run this query, I get an error message saying `“Name total_linear_touch_conversions not found inside d at [31:102]”`. I’m not sure what’s causing this error or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements and also provide sample input and output?